# Why can't i addChild after i remove all Child from stage?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

Why is that if i remove everything from stage, then i can't add anything back? It just became blank.

```
if(stage.numChildren > 0)
{
  stage.removeChildAt(0);
}

var s5:Autodetail= new Autodetail ();
     addChild(s5);
```

Comment: You haven't removed all children... only the child at 0th index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a while loop to remove all the children from the stage:

```
while(stage.numChildren > 0)
{
   stage.removeChildAt(0);
}
```

You should be able to add new things to the stage. Is there something wrong with

```
new Autodetail ()
```

?

Comment: I tried doing a while loop, then i have this error Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. and when i hit continue it removes everything. It might be from other codes that i have, i will have a look. But if i used if instead of while, it removes everything, but won't add the autodetail back on it

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to add s5 variable in context of current DisplayObject. It is not necessarily your stage and I guess it is exactly DisplayObject has been deleted by stage.removeChildAt(0).
Solution: use while loop and this instead of stage. It'll clean current childrens up while `this` object becomes stage's child.
Code:

```
if(this.numChildren > 0)
{
  this.removeChildAt(0);
}

var s5:Autodetail= new Autodetail ();
     this.addChild(s5);
```

Comment: And of course your Autodetail class should extend Sprite or DisplayObject to make addChild method call possible.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i fixed it,there were child added from another class file that i wanted to remove, i tried removing it by stage, but then i realized i have to call Global.classfilename instead of stage

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, since **Flash Player 11** you can simply call:

```
stage.removeChildren();
```

to remove all children from the stage or any DisplayObjectContainer.